# Using an Electribe 2 to sync with a Boss RC-300

Tags: midi, performing, midi-controller-keyboard, looping, looper-pedals

I have a Korg Electribe 2 sampler that I want to sync with a Roland Boss RC-300 looper.  I've Googled but what I've found doesn't show me a clear path forward.

```
    +---------+
    |Electribe|
    +-+------++
MIDI  |  Out | Audio
      |      |
      |      |
      v  In  v
    +------------+
    |Boss RC-300 +-----------> PA
    +------------+
         ^
         |
         |
       guitar
```

I want to have the Electribe both set the initial tempo, change the tempo and record Electribe audio loops to the RC-300 in real-time during live performances.

I think the audio part's pretty straight forward but how do I configure the Electribe's MIDI out and the RC-300's MIDI In to do this?

I have already tried the standard ways of syncing MIDI devices. The RC-300 has a non-standard MIDI sync process that only allows it--so far--to be the MIDI slave of another RC-300. For example, see:

- http://vguitarforums.com/smf/index.php?topic=13332.0
- http://www.vguitarforums.com/smf/index.php?topic=7678.0

Comment: It's unlikely that anybody else has done this with exactly these two devices. What do the two manuals say about this?

Comment: I need an answer to that http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/52648/how-to-send-electribe-2-midi-control-change-messages-using-sequencer-or-controls before I can answer this.

Comment: rc-300 can only serve as the master. - the manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't yet found a way to sync the Boss RC-300 from the Electribe 2 but I have found a way to sync the Electribe 2 from the Boss RC-300.

On the RC-300:

- Memory Edit
- Memory:MIDI Sync = INTERNAL

On the Electribe 2:

- Menu
- Global Parameter
- Clock Mode = AUTO

Set tempo and adjust tempos on the RC-300 using the Memory Edit, the tap tempo buttons or the stop pedal.

It's backwards to what I want to do, but it'll work until I can figure out the other way.

Another way of doing this is to use a midi sequencer or DAW to control both the Electribe and the RC-300. On the RC-300, go into Memory Edit, and page all the way to the end to Assign Controllers. I used controller 8, cause it didn't have any default assignments.Set it to ON, Target to MEM Tempo (tap), and for Source I used CC#64.

In your sequencer (Ableton Live or Reaper or anything that can edit and play MIDI files should work) create a 1 or 2 bar clip. This will contain only control data, not any notes. Draw in CC#64 on every beat, with a value of 127. If you want to be using the RC-300's rhythm track, then you only want to play this for a measure or 2, not loop it continuously, otherwise it retriggers the start of the pattern at every beat. Point the track to the MIDI out of your computer, and connect that to the MIDI in of the RC-300, and voila! The RC-300 will follow whatever tempo your sequencer is playing at.

Comment: The problem with this method is that when all the RC-300 loops stop, so does the Electribe.

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram shows the correct connections. What remains is the configuration of the devices. You have to make sure the Electribe is set to generate it's own clock signal **and** send that clock signal out of its MIDI port(s).

Then you have to set the Boss to not generate its own clock but instead to "slave" itself to external clock coming into its MIDI port(s). Once that is set correctly, it should either synchronize right away, or it will wait to synch until you press "play" on the Electribe.

Note that if you set it up this way and then power off, stop, or disconnect the Electribe, the Boss will have no clock and may not do anything at all until you set it back to its internal clock or start the Electribe clock again.

Comment: The RC-300 has a non-standard MIDI sync process that only allows it--so far--to sync with another RC-300. For example, see http://www.vguitarforums.com/smf/index.php?topic=13332.0

Comment: I have tried the standard ways of syncing MIDI devices before I asked this question.